# Problem when trying delete item from ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

I'm initialize my ComboBox using DataSource. After that when I'm trying to remove item from ComboBox I'm getting exception: "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set."

How can I remove items from ComboBox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify the datasource. Delete the item from the list that is bound to the combobox.